# How to specify user input in bash

Tags: ruby, bash, stdin, travis-ci

I am working on a Ruby program that I am using Travis CI to test automatically. The problem is that I can't specify the user input at each `gets.chomp`. I am trying to use `tee` and `echo` like below.

```
juniorRubyist@juniorRubyist-laptop:~/Projects/fitgem$ ./fitgem.rb <<< tee "hello"
Welcome to FitGem!
To get started, I need some information.
Please open your default browser and navigate to https://juniorRubyist.github.io/fitgem/authorize.html
Then authorize your Fitbit account.
Copy your Access Token: ./fitgem.rb:17:in `gets': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - hello (Errno::ENOENT)
    from ./fitgem.rb:17:in `gets'
    from ./fitgem.rb:17:in `initialize'
    from ./fitgem.rb:45:in `new'
    from ./fitgem.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

The problem is that it keeps thinking that I am trying to specify a file name and not a string. Am I doing something incorrectly or is it not supported. You can find the code at https://github.com/juniorRubyist/fitgem/blob/master/fitgem.rb if you want to see the code.

**EDIT 1:**
I tried this answer by *chepner*. Another error pops up.

```
joseph@Joseph-Ubuntu:~/Projects/fitgem$ ./fitgem.rb <<< "hello"
Welcome to FitGem!
To get started, I need some information.
Please open your default browser and navigate to https://juniorRubyist.github.io/fitgem/authorize.html
Then authorize your Fitbit account.
Copy your Access Token: Copy your User ID: ./fitgem.rb:19:in `initialize': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./fitgem.rb:45:in `new'
    from ./fitgem.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @chepner Please see EDIT 1 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<<` takes a single string to pass to the program.

```
./fitgem.rb <<< "hello"
```

It is roughly equivalent to

```
./fitgem.rb <<EOF
hello
EOF
```

Another alternative is a pipe

```
echo hello | ./fitgem.rb
```

---

`tee` duplicates its standard input to one or more files, as well as tostandard output.

```
$ echo hello | tee one.txt
hello
$ cat one.txt
hello
```

Comment: That's completely unrelated to shell; you have a problem with your Ruby script. It would be better to start a new question for that.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer.